# Cannot execute an anonymous code block with DO in Greenplum

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, greenplum

Greenplum Database (a PostgreSQL fork) is throwing an error everytime I try to execute a DO statement like the one below. Specifically, ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DO". Why is this? I'm running  Greenplum (version?) based on PostgreSQL 8.2.15.

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$
        BEGIN
            IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test) > 1 THEN
                CREATE TABLE test2 AS SELECT * FROM test
            END IF;
        END;
$$;
```

Mind you if I execute it as a function it works fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_maker ()
RETURNS void AS
$_$
BEGIN
            IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test) > 1 THEN
                    CREATE TABLE test2 AS SELECT * FROM test;
            END IF;
END $_$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT test_maker();
```

Comment: Anonymous code blocks appeared first in [v9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-9-0.html#AEN124353).

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: You're not using PostgreSQL at all. You are using Greenplum Database. It's a database product that's based on a heavily modified version of an old PostgreSQL. It is not PostgreSQL. It's a bit like saying "I'm using MySQL" when you're using Drizzle or Percona, but even more different. If you use Greenplum, say so, don't just refer to it as "PostgreSQL".

My advice to upgrade makes no sense if you're using Greenplum Database, since you're not actually using PostgreSQL 8.2.15 like you said, you're using some Greenplum Database version that claims to be Pg 8.2.15 at the protocol level (something I find intensely frustrating).

---

> Why is this? I'm running PostgreSQL 8.2.15

Use a PostgreSQL version that is not quite so pre-historic. As Milen noted, `DO` blocks were added in 9.0.

In general, whenever you find something that just doesn't get recognised by the SQL parser in PostgreSQL, functions that aren't recognised, etc, your first thought when you're running an ancient version should be "I'll check the manual for 8.2 and see if it's there".

You really, really, really need to upgrade anyway. Upgrade *immediately* to 8.2.23; you're missing some serious fixes. Then start planning for the upgrade to 8.4 or newer, preferably straight to 9.3. You'll have to deal with application compatibility issues caused by:

- Removal of implicit casts to text in 8.3
- `bytea_output` default change (update your client drivers if you use bytea, or change the setting)
- `standard_conforming_strings` default change (again, can change it back if you need to temporarily)
- Removal of backward compat support for implicit joins

Comment: Thank you. I wondered if this were the case, but couldn't find the documentation for when DO blocks were introduced. I would love to upgrade and have argued to this effect many times, but it's not my decision--and to my knowledge this is the latest version of postgres that greenplum runs on.